# array or list into Oracle using cfprocparam

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, coldfusion, tokenize, cfstoredproc

I have a list of values I want to insert into a table via a stored procedure.
I figured I would pass an array to oracle and loop through the array but I don't see how to pass an array into Oracle.  I'd pass a list but I don't see how to work with the list to turn it into an array using PL/SQL (I'm fairly new to PL/SQL). Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Using Oracle 9i and CF8.

EDIT

Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way?  I'm sure I'm not doing anything new here...
I figured I'd convert the list to an associative array then loop the array because Oracle doesn't seem to work well with lists (in my limited observation).

I'm trying to add a product, then add records for the management team.
-- product table

productName = 'foo'
productDescription = 'bar'
... 
...
etc

-- The managementteam table just has the id of the product and id of the users selected from a drop down.

The user IDs are passed in via a list like "1,3,6,20"

How should I go about adding the records to the management team table?

---

### Here is where I am code wise

In theory I pass a list "1,2,3,4" to inserts.addProduct.
inserts.addProduct should call tools.listToArray and return an array.
inserts.addProduct recreates a list with a * delim as a test.
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tools AS

```
  TYPE array_type is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(225) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION listToArray(in_list IN VARCHAR,
                     in_delim IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') 
  RETURN array_type;

END tools;



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tools
AS

FUNCTION listToArray(in_list IN VARCHAR,
                         in_delim IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') 
    RETURN array_type

    IS
    l_token_count BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    -- l_token_tbl type_array; 
    i pls_integer;
    l_start_pos INTEGER := 1;
    l_end_pos INTEGER :=1;
    p_parsed_table array_type;

    BEGIN -- original work by John Spencer  
       WHILE l_end_pos <> 0 LOOP
          l_end_pos := instr(in_list,in_delim,l_start_pos);
          IF l_end_pos <> 0 THEN
             l_token_count  := l_token_count  + 1;
             p_parsed_table(l_token_count ) :=
                      substr(in_list,l_start_pos,l_end_pos - l_start_pos);
             l_start_pos := l_end_pos + 1;
          END IF;
       END LOOP;
       IF l_token_count = 0 THEN /* We haven't parsed anything so */ 
          l_token_count := 1;
          p_parsed_table(l_token_count) := in_list;
       ELSE  /* We need to get the last token */ 
          l_token_count := l_token_count + 1;
          p_parsed_table(l_token_count) := substr(in_list,l_start_pos);
       END If;
       RETURN p_parsed_table;
    END listToArray;  -- Procedure

END tools;



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE inserts AS
    TYPE array_type is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(225) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    PROCEDURE addProduct (inList         IN  VARCHAR2,
                          outList        OUT VARCHAR2
                         );

END inserts;  




CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY inserts                      

    AS
    PROCEDURE addProduct (inList         IN  VARCHAR2,
                          outList        OUT VARCHAR2
                         )
    IS
    i NUMBER;
    localArray array_type := tools.listToArray(inList);
    BEGIN       
       outList := '';
       FOR i IN localArray.first .. localArray.last LOOP
          outList := outList || '*' ||localArray(i); -- return a string just to test this mess 
       END LOOP;

    END addProduct;

END inserts;
```

I'm currently getting an error "PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type" on localArray array_type := tools.listToArray(inList);

---

### final working code (thanks so much!)

-- create sql type collection

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_type is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(225);
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tools AS

  FUNCTION listToArray(in_list IN VARCHAR,
                     in_delim IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') 
  RETURN array_type;

END tools;   
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tools
AS

    FUNCTION listToArray(in_list IN VARCHAR,
                         in_delim IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') 
    RETURN array_type

    IS
    l_token_count BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    i pls_integer;
    l_start_pos INTEGER := 1;
    l_end_pos INTEGER :=1;
    p_parsed_table array_type := array_type();

    BEGIN
       WHILE l_end_pos <> 0 LOOP
          l_end_pos := instr(in_list,in_delim,l_start_pos);
          IF l_end_pos <> 0 THEN
             p_parsed_table.extend(1);
             l_token_count  := l_token_count  + 1;
             p_parsed_table(l_token_count ) :=
                      substr(in_list,l_start_pos,l_end_pos - l_start_pos);
             l_start_pos := l_end_pos + 1;
          END IF;

       END LOOP;
       p_parsed_table.extend(1);
       IF l_token_count = 0 THEN /* We haven't parsed anything so */ 
          l_token_count := 1;
          p_parsed_table(l_token_count) := in_list;
       ELSE  /* We need to get the last token */ 
          l_token_count := l_token_count + 1;
          p_parsed_table(l_token_count) := substr(in_list,l_start_pos);
       END If;
       RETURN p_parsed_table;
    END listToArray;  -- Procedure

END tools;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE inserts AS

    PROCEDURE addProduct (inList  IN  VARCHAR2,
                             outList OUT VARCHAR2
                         );

END inserts;
/




CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY inserts
AS
    PROCEDURE addProduct (inList  IN  VARCHAR2,
                          outList OUT VARCHAR2
                         )
    IS
    i NUMBER;
    mylist VARCHAR(100);
    localArray array_type := array_type();

    BEGIN     
    localArray := tools.listToArray(inList);
       mylist := '';
       FOR i IN localArray.first .. localArray.last LOOP
          mylist := mylist || localArray(i) || '*';
       END LOOP;
       aList := mylist;
    END addProduct;

END inserts;  
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL has supported arrays since Oracle 8.0.  They used to be called PL/SQL tables which confused the heck out of everybody, so now they are called collections.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#1059)

The problem is, that they are implemented as User-Defined Types (i.e. objects).  My reading of the [ColdFusion documents](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/tags-b16.htm) suggests that `cfprocparam` only supports the "primitive" datatypes (number, varchar2, etc).  So UDTs are not supported.

I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> I'd pass a list but I don't see how to
>   work with the list to turn it into an
>   array using PL/SQL

If you mean you want to pass a string of comma separated values ....

```
"Fox in socks, Mr Knox, Sam-I-Am, The Lorax"
```

then I have a workaround for you.  Oracle doesn't provide a built-in Tokenizer.  But a long time ago John Spencer published a hand-rolled solution which works in Oracle 9i on the OTN forums.  [Find it here.](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=508627#508627)

**edit**

> but... Oracle hates me

Do not despair.  The OTN forums have been upgraded a few times since John posted that , and the formatting seems to have corrupted the code somewhere along the way.  There were a couple of compilation errors which it didn't use to have.

I have rewritten John's code, including a new function.  THe main difference is that the nested table is declared as a SQL type rather than a PL/SQL type.

```
create or replace type tok_tbl as table of varchar2(225) 
/

create or replace package parser is

    function my_parse(
          p_str_to_search in varchar2
            , p_delimiter in varchar2 default ',')
          return tok_tbl;

    procedure my_parse(
          p_str_to_search in varchar2
          , p_delimiter in varchar2 default ','
          , p_parsed_table out tok_tbl);

end parser;
/
```

As you can see, the function is just a wrapper to the procedure.

```
create or replace package body parser is

    procedure my_parse ( p_str_to_search in varchar2
                          , p_delimiter in varchar2 default ','
                          , p_parsed_table out tok_tbl)
    is
        l_token_count binary_integer := 0;
        l_token_tbl tok_tbl := tok_tbl();
        i pls_integer;
        l_start_pos integer := 1;
        l_end_pos integer :=1;   
    begin

        while l_end_pos != 0
        loop
            l_end_pos := instr(p_str_to_search,p_delimiter,l_start_pos);

            if l_end_pos  != 0 then
                l_token_count := l_token_count + 1;
                l_token_tbl.extend();
                l_token_tbl(l_token_count ) :=
                    substr(p_str_to_search,l_start_pos,l_end_pos - l_start_pos);
                l_start_pos := l_end_pos + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;

        l_token_tbl.extend();
        if l_token_count = 0 then /* we haven't parsed anything so */
            l_token_count := 1;
            l_token_tbl(l_token_count) := p_str_to_search;
        else /* we need to get the last token */
            l_token_count := l_token_count + 1;
            l_token_tbl(l_token_count) := substr(p_str_to_search,l_start_pos);
        end if;
        p_parsed_table := l_token_tbl;
    end my_parse;

    function my_parse ( p_str_to_search in varchar2
                            , p_delimiter in varchar2 default ',')
                          return tok_tbl
    is
        rv tok_tbl;
    begin
        my_parse(p_str_to_search, p_delimiter, rv);
        return rv;
    end my_parse;

end parser;
/
```

The virtue of declaring the type in SQL is that we can use it in a FROM clause like this:

```
SQL> insert into t23
  2  select trim(column_value)
  3  from table(parser.my_parse('Fox in socks, Mr Knox, Sam-I-Am, The Lorax'))
  4  /

4 rows created.

SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

TXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fox in socks
Mr Knox
Sam-I-Am
The Lorax

SQL>
```

Comment: @APC - I believe there are also non-primitive types like cf_sql_array and cf_sql_struct. Do you know if either of those (java.sql.Types.Array or Struct) work with Oracle arrays in jdbc? As I do not work with Oracle, I have always been curious about that ;)

Comment: Sup Leigh.  No they don't work.  That's the first thing I tried but: [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver]The specified SQL type is not supported by this driver.

Comment: @Travis - That would have been too easy, right? ;) Obviously they are not supported by Adobe's driver. (Though I am curious if those types work with any Oracle driver ... Any thoughts @APC)?

Comment: @Leigh - Oracle provide their own equivalents - `oracle.sql.ARRAY` and `oracle.sql.STRUCT`.  I doubt they would have bothered doing so if the vanilla Java classes worked with PL/SQL collections.

Comment: @APC I think this is what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to convert this to a function and call it from my procedure but... Oracle hates me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit.  I actually figured out what was missing from the formatting.  I took the meat of the code and put that into a function returning my "array_type".  The problem i'm having is compiling the procedure that calls the function. I'm at home and don't have the code but it fails at localArray array_type := listToArray(managementTeam);  Error is wrong type or something like that.  Could it be because the listToArray function and addProduct procedure are in 2 different packages with 2 different array_type objects?

Comment: @APC - Yes, when you put it that way .. probably not ;) Thanks for the follow up.